# How to extend a class within a Ruby module

Tags: ruby, class, module, include, extend

I've been using OilyPNG (a set of C extensions for working with PNG's) and I'd like to start adding some of my own methods.  As such, I coded up a simple little C extension that creates the class `Hola` and includes the methods `Hola.bonjour` (which responds with a simple "hello") and `Hola.wazzup(input)` which spits the input right back.

OilyPNG is a module that contains a single class `:Canvas` with a bunch of methods `:decode_png_image_pass`, `:from_data_url`, `:from_rgb_stream`, etc.).  I'd like to add my methods (`bonjour` and `wazzup`) to the `Canvas` so I can start using them.  How do I do this?

It seems like this is a very basic Ruby question, but I can't seem to find it addressed anywhere.  I've tried (among MANY other things) the following:

```
module ChunkyPNG
  class Canvas
    include Hola
  end
end
```

...but it returns the following:

```
Error: #TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

All I want to do is something simple like creating a new Canvas object, then running my method, i.e. `OilyPNG::Canvas.new.bonjour` and I'm totally stuck.

UPDATE: The C code used to generate the extension

```
#include <ruby.h>

/* our new native method; it just returns the string "bonjour!" */
static VALUE hola_bonjour(VALUE self) {
    return rb_str_new2("bonjour, Zack!");
}

void Init_hola(void) {
    VALUE klass = rb_define_module("Hola"); /*DEFINED AS A MODULE*/

    rb_define_singleton_method(klass, "bonjour", hola_bonjour, 0);

}
```

UPDATE 2:

Finally got it working - using `rb_define module` in the C code, followed by defining the methods as `rb_define_method` (instead of as singletons).  Then build the gem, install it, then require the .so file, then open up OilyPNG to include the Hola module, as follows:

```
module OilyPNG
  class Canvas < ChunkyPNG::Canvas
    def your_method
      puts "hello"
    end
      include Hola
  end
end
```

Then load a png file as a test object:

```
test = OilyPNG::Canvas.from_file("C:/code/testfiles/orange.png"); nil
```

(the nil is to prevent Sketchup from crashing when it tries to send the PNG object to the command line), and then testing the output of:

```
test.bonjour
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module OilyPNG
  class Canvas < ChunkyPNG::Canvas # You must match the superclass when opening class and adding more definitions
    def your_method
      puts "hello"
    end
    include Hola # this will "insert" the Hola module at this point in the code... not sure what Hola contains so, not sure if that works or not.
  end
end
```

Looking at the source for OilyPNG the above should work...

Not sure why you got that error.  Given this works here is why:  You have to match the classes, super class when reopening it.

Based on this article: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html  by the great Peter Cooper, I believe you should be using `rb_define_method`, not `rb_define_singleton_method`

If you are still having trouble, start with peter's example, then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I've converted Hola to a module (see above) and tried out your code; Ruby likes it just fine.  And the your_method bit works just fine, but trying out the method from Hola it just kicks back an "undefined method" error.  And on its own, Hola.bonjour still works.  So bizarre.

Comment: can you post a small sample of what Hola looks like.  It seems that Hola is a module, but yet you say "As such, I coded up a simple little C extension that creates the class Hola" so perhaps somewhere in this is the problem

Comment: Sure - I've added the code above (simplified a bit; I pulled out the wazzup method).

Comment: Thanks - I actually can't even get Peter's code to work in irb (gets stuck on the require step).  I've tried out the rb_define_method path and that's no go either; the method doesn't show up at all anywhere.  If nothing else, I've learned a bit here, but this has been incredibly frustrating.  I need to set it aside or I'll go insane.

Comment: Well, I'm glad I didn't set it aside.  Finally got it working, and your stuff was a huge help.  I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You say that you

> [...] coded up a simple little C extension that creates the class "Hola"

so `Hola` is a class. But `include` expects a *module*, not a class. You have to rebuild your `Hola` as a module if you want to `include Hola` to patch `ChunkyPNG::Canvas`.

Consider this example:

```
class C
end
class D
  include C
end
```

That will give you exactly the same `TypeError` that you're seeing. However, if you say:

```
module M
end
class E
  include M
end
```

then it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks - I've done that (using VALUE klass = rb_define_module("Hola"); in the C code) and the error goes away, but unfortunately the new methods don't show up (if I try to use them, it kicks back an "undefined method" error and if I list the methods they aren't there).

Comment: So how are you defining your methods?

Comment: Do you mean inside the ruby environment?  Just by requiring the .so file from the installed gem.

Comment: No, how would I go about reproducing your problem?

Comment: It might be tough; it's taking place within the Ruby interface of Sketchup (plus there are a couple of additional layers; I'm packaging things as a gem and compiling that way cause I need it to run on Windows in Ruby 2.0.0 to work with Sketchup).  I'm worried that my problems are a result of that stuff; everything I've seen here WORKS both on a conceptual level and in fundamental ways in the interface, but just no love for my C extensions.  Probably my best bet is to pore through the OilyPNG source and see what's being done there that I'm missing.  I really do appreciate the help, though.

Comment: Have you checked that you C module really does look like you expect it to? You can do that without all the rest of the stuff in the way at least.